# rosbag record never finalized

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, i am new with ROS and I had the exiting challenge to build a lidar point cloud with a velodyne vlp-16.

I record my pacp file with tshark and now im in the ROS part.
With a lot of help in this forum i achieve starting roscore and also reading the pcap file with the velodyne driver.
My target is to get a .LAS file. After a couple of sample i figure that i had to convert my pcap to bag file in the process.

If at this point i'm not on the good way plz let me know :)

After many try i finaly got the **recording** with this:

```
rosrun rosbag record /velodyne_packets -O /media/lidar/math/test13.bag

[ INFO] [1512235521.473606088]: Subscribing to /velodyne_packets
[ INFO] [1512235521.542149460]: Recording to /media/lidar/math/test13.bag.
```

The problem is... it never ending. I can't figure what to do.

Any help is welcome,
thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277158/rosbag-record-never-finalized/) by [mathbeaudry](https://answers.ros.org/users/32841/mathbeaudry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What do you mean

> it never ending.

? Do you mean that the recording doesn't stop? If that's what you mean then you can just hit `Ctrl` + `c` and that will stop the recording.

If this *isn't* what you mean then please update your question to provide more details.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mathbeaudry](https://answers.ros.org/users/32841/mathbeaudry/) on 2017-12-02**:
yes, recording doesn't stop. every time, it create my file, but test13.bag never grow more than 4.1Kb in size whatever the size of my pcap file. That's why i pretend that recording dosen't do is job.

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2017-12-05**:
You have to make sure there is some node publishing on the `/velodyne_packets` topic, with
`rostopic echo /velodyne_packets`, for example.